# Manually creating a Flash AxHost.OcxState

Tags: c#, flash, interop

I am trying to use the `AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash` object in a **console** application in C#.  To do that, you have to set the `obj.OcxState` to something. I looked at how the Forms designer does that, and it does it this way:

```
this.flash.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("flash.OcxState")));
```

I looked in resources and there is nothing there.

My question is, how can I create an `AxHost.State` manually so I can set the `OcxState` of my flash object to it?

I see that the constructor of a `State` takes a `Stream`, `int`, `bool`, and a `string`. But I don't know what to put in the `Stream` (or the `int`, `bool`, or `string`) to create it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love this question :P, because setting the OcxState lets you dynamically load a Flash movie from a stream in memory, something I've seen asked here and there without a reply ever (maybe it is now, dunno). I realized about this two years ago while working on an important project, and left it aside for three or so hours until I got this working.

As the stream you can use any stream, a MemoryStream is enough (in order to fill it you can use a BinaryWriter), to set the OcxState just do:

```
flashCtl.OcxState = new AxHost.State(stream, 1, false, null);
```

If the resources file has the OcxState entry empty, maybe it is because the Flash OCX lets you set an empty stream with no problems, that's something I don't know.

Comment: And I can't even remember why I needed to do this. Thanks very much for the answer though, I'll keep it in mind for when I remember :)

Comment: Heh, I didn't even realize this question was a couple of months old, well, it may be of help to other people in the future as well.

Comment: @Neverbirth Got a question about the OcxState: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735616/activex-initialization-axhost-state-object