# ActiveX initialization: AxHost.State object

Tags: c#, .net, activex, unity-game-engine, axhost

I'm trying to embed a Unity3D-ActiveX control into a WPF-Form by using a WinFormsHost-Control.

Actually it works well when setting the path in the property window of VS, but when setting it in my code file it does not load anything. This is a known issue of the control but i thought i can simply copy the creation code of the forms-designer and initialize it manually.

When looking at the code of the initialization i noticed that there is no `src` property in the code, but the property is used in the property window. Setting the property manually does not work ( throws a error ).

After some test's i decided to check the hole assembly for the `src` property, but the `src` property is never set and i can't even find the string of the path.

#### Final thoughts

I noticed that there can be only one place where the src-path is located: The resource generated by the window forms designer, which is a object of the [AxHost.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost.state.aspx)-type.

#### Question

How do i create a valid `AxHost.State` object to initialize the Unity3D-ActiveX control which should load a Unity3D-file specified by me?

Comment: Use the vendor's support channels to find support.

Comment: @HansPassant We are talking here about the `AxHost.State` object, not about unity itself. The state object is generated by visual studio.

Comment: Found a solution which works, but it's nothing more than a hack. I modified the existing activeX object src path, saved the state in a local variable, disposed the existing ActiveX object, created a new one by using the state which has been saved in the local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution which works but is a little bit slow( Note: You need to initialize the Control once in the Forms Designer and copy the OcxState object into the assembly resources ):

```
// Create a ocx state object with the correct path
_Unity = new AxUnityWebPlayerAXLib.AxUnityWebPlayer();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(_Unity)).BeginInit();
_Unity.OcxState = (AxHost.State)(Resources.Unity3DOcx);
_Unity.TabIndex = 0;
Controls.Add(_Unity);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(_Unity)).EndInit();
_Unity.src = _File;
AxHost.State state = _Unity.OcxState;
_Unity.Dispose();

// Create the unity web player object
_Unity = new AxUnityWebPlayerAXLib.AxUnityWebPlayer();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(_Unity)).BeginInit();
this.SuspendLayout();
_Unity.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
_Unity.Name = "Unity";
_Unity.OcxState = state;
_Unity.TabIndex = 0;
Controls.Add(_Unity);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(_Unity)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a parameter into disableContextMenu property in ActiveX Unity Web player, you need to prepare IPropertyBag.Read Method in your program.

I made a sample C++ program (Visual Studio 2010) which set "true" parameter into disableContextMenu property. See http://www.nibiirosoft.com/download/UnityActiveXSample.zip

And using that codes, I made a player for .unity3d files (http://www.nibiirosoft.com/Product/UniPlayer.html).

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Decompiling the dll "`AxUnityWebPlayerAXLib`" and adding the `src` parameter directly in the code solves the problem.

Everything works fine, but I still have a problem with "`disableContextMenu`".

Comment: Added my solution. I hope this helps. Never tested the disableContextMenu thing...